# AngularJS NgOnInIt method losing data on the second visit to my component using router-link

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router, ngoninit

I have a component called edit-scrim and inside my component i have 2 arrays of type model "Team", i am using some methods from a service i imported into the component to assign values to the array. On my first visit to the page the arrays are being populated just fine but if i go to another page using router.navigate() and comeback to "edit-scrim" using a routerlink it loses the data for 1 of the arrays. All my functionality to assign data to array is inside ngOnInit and i have done a console.log("check") inside this method to see if it is even being called every time i visit the component and **IT IS** being called so i am not sure what is wrong.

**If i refresh my page the data comes back, but if i visit it through a routerlink again it does not**

These are my arrays in the component.ts file

```
teams: Team[];
myTeams: Team[] = [];
```

Attached is the code snippet for my ngOnInIt method, i use a routerlink to visit another page and comeback to the "edit-scrim" and data is gone.

```
 ngOnInit() {
 console.log("check");
 this.myinit();

 }

 myinit() {



 this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {
  if (auth) {
    this.loggedInUser = auth.email;
  } else {

  }
 });

 this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
  this.teams = teams;
  console.log(this.teams);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.teams.length; i++) {
    if (this.teams[i].createdBy == this.loggedInUser) {
      this.myTeams.push(this.teams[i]);
    }
  }

 });

 console.log(this.myTeams);


 this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

 //Get Team
 this.scrimService.getScrim(this.id).subscribe(scrim => {
  this.scrim = scrim;
 });


 }
```

[console.log info after visiting the page twice](https://ibb.co/jbpx15)

**EDIT**
When i do this inside my init function, the first time i visit my page it console.logs the right data, if i go to another page and come back to this, it is lost. :/

```
    this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
    this.teams = teams;
    console.log(this.teams);

   // this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(function (team) { return 
   team.createdBy == this.loggedInUser; });
   this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(team => team.createdBy == 
   this.loggedInUser)
   console.log(this.myTeams);


   });
```

**EDIT2**

```
 this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.loggedInUser = auth.email;
        this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
      this.teams = teams;
      console.log(this.teams);

   //this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(function (team) { return team.createdBy == this.loggedInUser; });
    this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(team => team.createdBy == this.loggedInUser)
    console.log(this.myTeams);


    });
      } else {

      }
    });
```

**EDIT3 -> Didn't work this way :/ maybe i messed up syntax?**

```
this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.loggedInUser = auth.email;
      }
    },
      error => { console.log(error) },
      () => {
        this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
          this.teams = teams;
          this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(team => team.createdBy == this.loggedInUser);
          console.log(this.teams);
          console.log(this.myTeams);
        });
      });
```

**EDIT 4 - didn't work, it is not even getting to the stage of doing console.log**

```
this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.loggedInUser = auth.email;
      }
    },
      error => { console.log(error) },
      () => {
        this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
          this.teams = teams;
          this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(team => team.createdBy == this.loggedInUser);
          console.log(this.teams);
          console.log(this.myTeams);
        });
      });
```

Comment: It seems that you are reinitializing the second array on every call: myTeams: Team[] = [];

Comment: if i do myTeams[]: Team[]; -> this gives error can't push into undefined or myTeams[] = new Array<Team> it still doesn't work. What can i do?

Comment: You can use a filter on the original array like this: this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(team => team.createdBy == this.loggedInUser).

Comment: I forget to mention that you need ES6 for this, if you are using ES5 you can use it like this: this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(function (team) { return team.createdBy == this.loggedInUser; }

Comment: Do i have to change anything in my initialization of the array? also should i do this function right after i subscribe teams into this.teams or outside that subscribe function?

Comment: Yes, delete the initialization at the declaration part. Also, you do filtering on the array instead of for loop.

Comment: it says cannot read property filter of undefined, when i removed the initialization

Comment: You need to put filter line just beneath this line: this.teams = teams;

Comment: can you check edit, i tried that.

Comment: my initialization looks like this now
teams: Team[];
myTeams:Team[];

P.S i use a routerLink to go to another page and come back to the page i need the data on, if that makes a difference. I first thought problem lies within the subscribe but somehow the original array retains the data. :/

Comment: How are you "coming back"? Is the ngOnInit fired when you return?

Comment: yes it is firing because i can see my console.log("check") and console.log(this.teams), and lastly console.log(this.myTeams) ->this comes back as empty array. If possible can i teamviewer with you to show you what i mean.

Comment: I think I know whats going on. You have two async calls to services, one to auth and other to team services. If team services is resolved first then you still have "nothing" from auth service and cannot filter - that's why your other array is empty. You need to chain those two calls - first you do the auth and then team services.

Comment: could you show me an example of "chaining" the calls, i am extremely noob at angular/typescript

Comment: So, you have chained it in a way :) I will post you little later more "elegant" way to do it.

Comment: can you check edit and see if that is fine, it is working .

Answer (score 0):

Your team service call is dependant on successful completion of the auth service call, so you need to "chain" it together. The easiest way to do it is to put the second call in first subscribe's code block that runs only if the call is successfully executed:

```
.subscribe(
    function(response) { //code that handles response },
    function(error) { // error handling },
    function() { // code that runs after completion }
);
```

So in your case you will have something like this:

```
myinit() {
    this.authService.getAuth().subscribe((auth) => {
        if (auth) {
            this.loggedInUser = auth.email;
        }
    },
    (error) => { console.log(error); },
    () => {
           this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
           this.teams = teams;
           this.myTeams = this.teams.filter(team => team.createdBy == this.loggedInUser);
    });
 });
}
```

Comment: can you check the edit, thanks - my list is empty and no error log in console

Comment: Check it now, I have messed up with closing brackets.